# How do I catch this exception in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: exception, mfc, indexoutofboundsexception

I encountered this issue in my application. Hitting the debug button provided this detail:

```
Exception thrown: write access violation.

std::map<ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >,bool [52],std::less<ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > > >,std::allocator<std::pair<ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > > const ,bool [52]> > >::operator[](...) was 0x111026CE50857E9.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

The code it fell over on was:

```
m_mapStudentAssignedStudyPoints[strName][iStudyPoint] = false;
```

The definition of that variable:

```
const int kMaxStudyPointCount = 52;
typedef map<CString, bool[kMaxStudyPointCount]> AssignedStudyPoints;    
AssignedStudyPoints m_mapStudentAssignedStudyPoints;
```

I would love to give you a sample application but it is a huge application. It looked to me that it fell over on the [] assignment.

I did more investigation and **iStudyPoint** was set to **65535** (which I understand to be -1). My bool array is limited to 0-51 so I am not surprised it asserted.

I have now resolved the root cause of having 65535 in my code. But, my question, is what type of **try/catch** statement do I use so that I can catch this kind of issue when assigning my map entry content?

Comment: Did you investigate what happens right _before_ the exception ? Maybe `iStudyPoint` is already 65535. Try to put an `ASSERT(iStudyPoint >= 0 && iStudyPoint <= 51);`.

Comment: Exactly. I found that that was the case. And then resolved it from happening in the first place. But how does one catch when you are assigning a out of bounds index? ASSERT only works in debug doesn't it?

Comment: How about some unit testing?

Comment: @rrirower What do you mean? I am now testing the unit values elsewhere in the application (serializing source data from disk). I am asking what **exception** I need to trap to detect out of bounds. Thanks.

Comment: If you used something like [GTest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Test) you might be able to head off any potential problems.

Comment: I have never heard of **GTest**. But I will check it out. Thanks.

Comment: Access violations on Windows are implemented using [Structured Exception Handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657.aspx). You could catch an access violation by [using SEH in C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swezty51.aspx) through the `__try`/`__except` compiler extensions. Be careful not to mix C++ and SEH exceptions, and make sure to not swallow any exceptions that should propagate up. The solution is obviously to fix the bug. If you would rather keep going with thrashed data, this is how you would do it.